# ProxyPass not overriding .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxypass

We have an angular app with an apache server which uses .htaccess to rewrite requests to /index.html using

`RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`

But for a few paths, we want to use /whatever to route to a different domain. However, adding

`ProxyPass /whatever whatever.site.com`

to sites-enabled doesn't seem to override the .htaccess.
That full file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ProxyPass /whatever https://whatever.com
    ProxyPassReverse /whatever https://whatever.com

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Any suggestions?

Also, I know for sure that the sites-enabled file above is being used because if I put garbage-text into it the site crashes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your quoted virtualhost is probably not used for your test request, because proxy would always bypass mod_rewrite rules specified in .htaccess.

Maybe apachectl -S would give you a hint about which vhosts are present / being used.  I see this vhost has no ServerName, so unless it's the first or only *:80 it will probably never be used.